# Coordinate correction of object in 3D space by using quaternion

Tags: python, translation, quaternions

I have an object which is in 3D space. A marker is attached to the object. The marker gives me (X,Y,Z) of the object with respect to an origin. The markers also gives the quaternion of that point (A,B,C,D). The marker on the object are not placed at the center of object.

I want to correct the marker coordinate so that the marker position gets translated to the center of the object along the X axis of the origin. Given the distance between the marker position and center of object is a number 'K'.

How do I use the quaternions to correct the marker coordinate?. I am really stuck with this for a while, any solution would be a great help to me.Thanks in advance.

Using scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation I can get the rotation matrix, euler angle or rotation vector for a given (X,Y,Z) of the marker.
The image below shows a set of points taken from a motion capture sensor.

My code:

```
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R
quat=[-0.018853,0.801030,0.022920,0.597888]  #A,B,C,D quaterion of a point (x,Y,Z)
r = R.from_quat([quat])
rot_matix=r.as_dcm() #rotation matrix 
rot_vector=r.as_rotvec()
```

This is the information that I have from the quaterion values.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9VsR.png]

Comment: Post your code to give insight how to help you.

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9VsR.png) This are the coordinate and quaternion generated from a motion capture sensor.

Comment: post your link in the question... use ![ desciption here ]( link ) without the whitespaces, also the code you tried sofar. No need to reinvent the wheel and we can see where you got stuck.

Comment: It would be also helpful if you can explain it intuitively how to do the translation with the informations available

Comment: firstly, my comments are to get your question on to par and prevent downvotes. Second, I think I understand what you want to accomplish. Its something I need to do my self as well in a few days. Give me a few days and I'll probably pop an answer. Its all about keeping track of identified object. Your quaternoin is time, right?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Quaternion here represents orientation of the object in open space with respect to a origin. Each value are given for time. I am trying to figure out the problem,. Hopefully if I do I will post the answer here.

Comment: Where you perhaps want to look into during the weekend is OpenCV. It has tracking abilities.